# John 15:16 Exogete of ΕΘΗΚΑ

Tags: greek, john

John 15:16a
"You did not choose me, but I chose you and appointed you so that you might go and bear fruit—fruit that will last"

The word used, ΕΘΗΚΑ, can be translated to appointed/ordained.
Is this evidence of Jesus giving his apostles a priesthood authority?

I only have access to the TR and I see the word used in Luke 19:22 as well.

Comment: [The NA28 is available online](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/53/150016/150016/ch/21f6d77f3cb381549384849128e417d6/) if you prefer. Please also specify the English translation you’re using. (FYI the lexical form is τίθημι, and this is a very common word [96x in NA28]. The usage in John 15:16 is specific and may be interesting, but it appears to be unrelated to Luke 19:22 [except that it happens to be inflected similarly], so I would recommend removing that.)

Comment: It [looks like NIV](http://biblehub.com/john/15-16.htm) to me; note also the [Greek tools and texts](http://biblehub.com/text/john/15-16.htm) (also [these](http://biblehub.com/texts/john/15-16.htm)) available at that site.

Comment: I appreciate the tool references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word τίθημι, for which ἔθηκα is one form (an aorist), means literally to "place" or "set".  Other examples, using the RSV translation:

**Matthew 5:15**

> *Nor do men light a lamp and **put** it under a bushel, but on a stand, and it gives light to all in the house.*

**Mark 6:29**

> *When his disciples heard of it, they came and took his body, and **laid** it in a tomb.*

**Luke 21:14**

> ***Settle*** it therefore in your minds, not to meditate beforehand how to answer

Although there are certainly passages in the Gospel that show Jesus appointing to the Apostles to a special ministry (e.g. John 20:21-23), I do not think this is the focus here.

The Byzantine (Greek) commentator, Theophylact, understood ἔθηκα to refer to "planting" in this particular verse, especially in view of what follows:  *that you should go and bear fruit and that your fruit should abide*.  This would be also be consistent with how the word is occasionally used in the Septuagint - e.g.

**Genesis 2:8 LXX**

> *And God planted* [ἔθετο] *a garden in Eden, in the east ...*

Theophylact explains:

> Furthermore, I *appointed you*, meaning, I *planted you*, that
>   ye should go - that is grow, increase, spread - and bring forth
>   fruit."  Here Jesus clearly portrays Himself as the Husbandman of the
>   vineyard. When He said above *Ye are purged through the word which I
>   have spoken unto you* [v.3], He presented Himself as the one who does
>   the pruning.  Now He is more explicit:  "*I have* also *chosen you,
>   and* planted *you*."  It is the husbandman who chooses the branches
>   and plants them in the earth.
>
> *Explanation of the Gospel According to John* (tr. Chrysostom Press, 2007), p.242

Comment: (-1) The Theophylact commentary is not at all cogent, particularly as it does not appear within the context of John 15:1-8 and undermines your answer.